# How to combine Swift and C code in a static library

Tags: c, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a static library that contains Swift and C code, and exposes only a Swift interface. So the C code side should ideally not be exposed to the outside world. I can't seem to figure out the right way to do this without causing warnings or errors.

For the sake of simplification, I tried setting up a minimal Swift+C static library with these files:

**Test.swift**

```
class Test {
    func test() -> CInt {
        return testFromC()
    }
}
```

**Test.c**

```
#include "Test.h"

int testFromC(void) {
    return 0xdeadbeef;
}
```

**Test.h**

```
int testFromC(void);
```

What I want is a static library that exposes the Swift class `Test`, but not the C function `testFromC()`. I can live with it being exposed if there is no alternative, though.

What I have tried is:

1. Add a bridging header. This almost works, but a) lots of people say this is not supported or recommended, b) it exposes `testFromC()` to the importer of the module, and c) under some circumstances it throws warnings about implicitly importing the bridging header (which is true, but what I want is specifically to NOT do that).
2. Add a modulemap. I can't figure out how to do this. No examples online seem to work for me, and if anyone knows how to do this correctly, I would love to see an example for these three files.
3. Add a private modulemap - I gather this is what I want if I want to avoid exposing the C functions but I had even less success with this.

Is anyone able to put together the exact steps to make this trivial example build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed create a private module map so that the C symbols are not exported, see https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#private-module-map-files.

The bridging header would not work because you want to create a framework and not an application.

There are certainly several ways to set up the project, one of which would be: create a project with the corresponding module map settings in XCode.

The `.modulemap` file could look something like this:

```
framework module SwiftOnlyAPI {
    umbrella header "SwiftOnlyAPI.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}

framework module SwiftOnlyAPI_Private {
    header "Test.h"
}
```

Your `Test.swift` would rather look something like this:

```
import SwiftOnlyAPI_Private

public class Test {
    public init() {
        //perform some initializations
    }
    
    public func test() -> CInt {
        return testFromC()
    }
}
```

Please note a few small changes: the import of `SwiftOnlyAPI_Private`, this is necessary for the C functions that are not exported, but of course are called locally within the framework. Classes and exported methods must be public to be accessible from outside the framework.

**Instructions**

- <File/New Project...> choose `Framework`, choose Language `Swift` name it `SwiftOnlyAPI`
- add you files (.c,.h,.swift) to the `SwiftOnlyAPI` folder
- select `Test.h` in the project navigator and switch the target membership in the inspector from `Project` to `Private`
- choose `SwiftOnlyAPI` in the project navigator, select the `SwiftOnlyAPI` target
- now click on `Build Settings` and for `Mach-O Type` select: `Static Library`
- still in `Build Settings`: for `Module Map File` enter: `SwiftOnlyAPI/SwiftOnlyAPI.modulemap`
- select the folder `SwiftOnlyAPI` in the `SwiftOnlyAPI` project, choose `New File...` from the context menu and, choose `Empty` template from the `Other` section and name it `SwiftOnlyAPI.modulemap` (uncheck target membership)
- add the modulemap content shown above

A test produces the desired result, just as shown for the alternative solution for multiple targets below.

**Static Library**

Frameworks are really just either dynamic or static libraries (depending on the setting) with additional bundled files. Convenient for the framework users.

You can test this yourself with the `file` command:

[image: output of file command]

**Alternative**

If you want to have the C part separate (e.g. for other consumers), you can also split it into two subprojects in an Xcode workspace, one for a static C lib and one for a static Swift-based framework:

- create a XCode workspace <File/New Workspace...>, e.g. name it `SwiftCWorkspace`
- <File/New Project...> choose `Library`, choose under Framework `None (Plain C/C++ Library)`, name it `MyCLib` and choose type `Static`
- in the dialog choose for `Add to` and `Group`: `SwiftCWorkspace`
- select the `MyCLib` node in project navigator, choose `New File...` from the context menu and choose C file template, name it Test
- replace the content with your Test.c and Test.h content
- <File/New Project...> choose `Framework`, choose Language `Swift` name it `SwiftOnlyAPI`
- in the dialog choose for `Add to` and `Group`: `SwiftCWorkspace`
- select the folder `SwiftOnlyAPI` in the `SwiftOnlyAPI` project, choose `New File...` from the context menu and, choose `Swift` template and replace it with your ccontent
- choose `SwiftOnlyAPI` in the project navigator, select the `SwiftOnlyAPI` target
- now click on `Build Settings` and for `Mach-O Type` select: `Static Library`
- still in `Build Settings`: for `Module Map File` enter: `SwiftOnlyAPI/SwiftOnlyAPI.modulemap`
- now click on `General` and in the `Frameworks and Library` section add `libMyCLib.a`
- select the folder `SwiftOnlyAPI` in the `SwiftOnlyAPI` project, choose `New Group...` from the context menu and name it `MyCLib`
- drag & drop `Test.h` from `MyCLib` project to the `MyCLib` folder in `SwiftOnlyAPI`, uncheck `Copy items if needed`
- with the newly linked file `Test.h` selected switch the target membership in the inspector from `Project` to `Private`
- select the folder `SwiftOnlyAPI` in the `SwiftOnlyAPI` project, choose `New File...` from the context menu and, choose `Empty` template from the `Other` section and name it `SwiftOnlyAPI.modulemap` (uncheck target membership)
- add the modulemap content shown above

**Notes**

If Xcode displays error messages even though you have set everything up correctly, it is occasionally necessary to exit Xcode after the project setup tasks, delete the `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` folder, and then restart the build.

**Test**

```
import SwiftOnlyAPI

    ...

    let result = SwiftOnlyAPI.Test()
    print(result.test())
```

You can test this in a separate application using the SwiftOnlyAPI framework: the correct result will be output.

Also the C function `testFromC` is private and not externally accessible as desired, see screenshot:
[image: test]

Comment: This looks like it might work, but it seems a bit overly complicated, since it involves multiple targets. Also, ideally I want a single static library as the product, not a framework.

Comment: The important thing is the structure of the .modulemap file and the setting for the private header file. I have added a variant to the answer where everything happens in a single Xcode project. Frameworks are really just either dynamic or static libraries with additional bundled files. Handy for consumers of the framework, see the updated answer.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I see many references saying that there is no such thing as a "static framework". Frameworks are dynamic, and static libraries are just .a files. Putting a static .a inside a framework isn't really supposed to be supported?

For instance, if you put a resource into this "static framework", will it actually be included in the app or will it just be ignored?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure there are dynamic and static frameworks. The relevant setting is `Mach-O Type`: it is either `Static Library` or `Dynamic Library`.  A static library is an `ar` archive.  You can test this yourself. See the screenshot of the `file` command in the answer, instead of `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library` it prints `current ar archive random library`. In the terminal, you can also run `ar -t SwiftOnlyAPI` command for static framework to output the contents of this `ar` archive.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question about resources correctly. With static linking, the code is placed into the final executable file.  The actual framework would not be embedded as a folder in the app bundle. You can include resources separately, for example, in the app itself or in a separate bundle. But maybe I didn't understand the question correctly. Sounds like a separate topic either way though.

Comment: You said "Frameworks are really just either dynamic or static libraries with additional bundled files", and I am saying that I don't think you can really have static frameworks with bundled files. So overall it seems to be the wrong approach to try to generate a "static framework" here, it should be a plain static library, not any kind of framework.

Comment: Ah, ok. For example, static frameworks also have a bundled `info.plist` that contains information about the compiler used, for example. Arbitrary separate resource files (e.g. images), can indeed not be used as mentioned above (neither when using a static framework nor a static library).

Comment: I don't think that is a "static framework". It's just a static library that happens to sit inside a folder that looks like a framework, but isn't actually. The correct thing to do here would be to build a static library, and not a framework. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Hm, I would even argue that this has been the definition of a "static framework" for years. Admittedly, the term was probably coined outside of Apple, and the original meaning of framework referred to bundling a dynamic library with infos and resources. But it is widely used, e.g. if you download Firebase versions over the years like https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/releases/download/6.19.0/Firebase-6.19.0.zip and apply `file FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics` you get `current ar archive`. Another very prominent example is the static linkage option of CocoaPods.

Comment: Well, that is the thing: It's a word for something that Apple has not created or support, and it doesn't really make sense. From trying to look this up, Apple seems pretty adamant that there is not such thing as a "static framework", and therefore I'd prefer to avoid trying to create one, but rather use what is actually supported.